# With numpy array mask only a single column

Tags: python, numpy

I want to mask only col 0 in my 2D array `strut[i].rpsi`. Below works and mask col 0 correctly but it also mask col 1.

```
mask = ~(strut[i].rpsi <= time.time() - apsiTimeWindow)
```

Output of above is:

```
[[False False]
 [True False]
 [True False]]
```

I need an output like so:

```
[[False True]
 [True True]
 [True True]]
```

or even better:

```
[[False]
 [True]
 [True]]
```

Comment: What are the value of the variables `i` and `apsiTimeWindow`? What does your 2D array look like?

Comment: @PhilipTzou Figured out the answer. `np.vstack(strut[i].rpsi[:,0])` returns col 0 masked. It outputs exactly the same as the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Below does what I need.

```
mask = ~(np.vstack(strut[i].rpsi[:,0]) <= time.time() - apsiTimeWindow)
```

This will output only col 0 masked.